# Rebus - Multiple Transports

Tags: rebus

Using Rebus, is it possible to have more than one transport configured within an application?

Our business domain is image processing, due to the potentially large size of the images being processed, I would like to use an InMemory transport for communication within one service (WebApi 2) to tokenize (Guid) and persist the images to be processed into a database.

In addition, after the images are tokenized we would like to used the RabbitMQ transport to send the images for processing to the ImageProcessingService (Console App - using TopShelf), and reply back to the calling application (WebApi) once processing is complete.

I cant seem to figure out the correct way to handle the scenario where I would like to use messaging within an application (WebApi) using an InMemory transport, and also have the WebApi able to send to the ImageProcessingService via the RabbitMQ Transport.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously I don't know the details of your problem, but did you consider saving the image data somewhere else (a network share, MongoDB GridFS, a SQL Server LOB, etc)?

In my experience everything turns out to be easier to handle if you use messages for coordination only, and not so much for transporting the actual bulk of the data.

---

PS: I did experiment with a *multi-modal transport* at some point, which would allow you to do something like this:

```
Configure.With(...)
    .Transport(c => c.Multi()
        .Add("amqp", t => t.UseRabbitMq(connStr, "rabbitqueue")
        .Add("inmem", t => t.UseInMemoryTransport(network, "inmemqueue"))
    .Start();
```

and then specify addresses on the form `amqp://rabbitqueue` and `inmem://inmemqueue` to address the configured endpoint via RabbitMQ and in-mem transports respectively.

It would simple wrap any number of transports which you would then need to qualify with a protocol, which could be anything you would feel would be appropriate.

This way of addressing turned out to raise a bunch of questions though, so it wasn't that simple to introduce.

Comment: isn't introduction of multi transport against Rebus philosophy to have only one input queue? how would it even work - would it take one message from first transport, one from second and so on in loop? I could imagine one use that like .Add("msmq1") .Add("msmq2"). I guess having separate busses for each queue is simpler to reason about :)

Comment: that's what I meant by "it raises a bunch of questions" ;-) but yes, the transport wrapper would simply alternate between receiving from each wrapped transport, and the return address would be set to a semicolon-separated list of all input queue address the endpoint could be found on, + some more stuff to tie things together... it was actually able to send/receive messages, but there would still be lots of questions :)